# Delete document from Firestore not consistent

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I built an Angular8 app connected to Firestore and I'm dealing with an unexpected result from a delete promise on a Firestore document. I have a collection of 'users' with each 'xyz'-user a document. The code below that I use now gets the delete job done only on a user **existing in Firestore before** the app was loaded.

```js
        this.db.collection('users').doc('xyz').delete()
         .then(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
          this.uiService.showSnackbar(user.name + ' is now gone!', null, 
           3000);
         }).catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
        });
```

The issues start when I create a **new user** in Firestore from the app and try to delete it. The code doesn't throw an error, the then() part - router/snackbar - is executed alright but the new user document in Firestore is not deleted. I have to reload the app/page to be able to delete the same newly added user. The reload does the trick but I would like to understand the reason why and avoid it altogether. Sorry if my explanation seems convoluted, it's my first question on SO.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you call this "piece of code"? We need to see the code that write to the database and how it is "articulated" with this code.

Comment: My first guess is that you're creating the user-document *after* the code snippet you shared is run. With some logging in your app you should be able to prove that. If you're still having problems, you'll need to show us the "document creation" code *and* the deletion code you already showed, in a way that we can run it ourselves to reproduce the problem. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).